# Fix bootstrap side panel when scroll down

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

According to example [here](http://www.bootply.com/render/88105) side panel is fix as i expected. But when i scroll down, side panel is animated little bit or overlapping. can't understand what happen. how to avoid it? [image]

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the affix-top class. When you are on the top of the page you have this <div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="45" data-offset-bottom="90" class="affix-top"> and after this <div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="45" data-offset-bottom="90" class="affix">. I don't now how it works exactly but it create the jump. If you have only affix as class it should works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is div which have class `affix-top` change it to `affix` will solve your issue.

```
<div class="affix-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="45" data-offset-bottom="90">
```

To

```
<div class="affix" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="45" data-offset-bottom="90">
```

like:

```
<div data-offset-bottom="90" data-offset-top="45" data-spy="affix" class="affix">
            <ul id="sidebar-nav" class="nav">
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>     
              <li><a href="#section4">Section 4</a></li>     
            </ul>
</div>
```